# Change image source on mouseover then get the image back on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

```
<img src="img/image1.png" id="mainimage">

<p><a href="#" id="pet1">Dog</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="pet2">Cat</a></p>
```

I am trying to use JavaScript/jQuery so that whenever a user places their mouse over any of the links with the id's pet1 & pet2 it will change the image `src` of the image with the id of mainimage.

```
var img = document.getElementById('swap');
document.getElementById('pet1').onmouseover = function(){
    // manipulate the image source here.
    img.src = img.src.replace(/\.jpg/, '-on.jpg');
}
```

The above JavaScript is a script I  found here that seems to have the functionality I am looking for. The only problem is that whenever my mouse is over the link it does not display the image I want. Ok, the question I am looking for is how can I make the image with the source (img/pet1.jpg) appear?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: any specific reason you want to do this with javascript?? CSS has a very simple solution for this

Comment: @Alexandros — No, it doesn't. It's a content image, not a background image.

Comment: @Quentin What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/380/

Comment: Guys whatever works really CSS, JAVASCRIPT, Whatever. Just something that work would be awesome.

Comment: @GuyT — Doesn't work in Firefox (haven't tested in any IE).

Comment: @Quentin That true, it also doesn't work in IE. It all depends on the project requirements. If you only need to support Chrome it's an excellent solution, though.

Comment: I just need something that works similar to that. Something that can support on most browsers. It can be based on css or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.

For all links at once we set a mouseover handler (which takes the ID of the link, turns it into a path to the image, and displays it) and a mouseout handler (which reverts the image's `src` to its original image).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // To start with, get a reference to the image and its original src
    var $mainImage = $('#mainimage'),
        originalImageSrc = $mainImage.attr('src');

    // Then add mouseover and mouseout handlers to all the links
    $('a')
        .on('mouseover', function() {
            var newImageSrc = 'img/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg';
            $mainImage.attr('src', newImageSrc);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function() {
            $mainImage.attr('src', originalImageSrc);
        });
});
```

You can see it working in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s1fx4hL/1/). So that you can see it working in the JSFiddle without real images, I've used a `div`'s `text` rather than an `img`'s `src`, but that's just for the demo.

Of course you could always adapt it (maybe you want to be more specific than *all `a` tags*, and maybe you don't always want to use the format `img/<id>.jpg` – in which case you could add a `data-img-src` attribute to all your links and use `.data('imgSrc')` instead of the `.attr('id')`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Uhh, I want to add in a new image source to the mainimage that goes like this: img/name4.jpg where can I add that in??? sorry I am barley new to this.

Comment: Well then after your `<p><a href="#" id="pet2">Cat</a></p>` just add another one of `<p><a href="#" id="name4">Name 4</a></p>` – everything will work automatically, it will pick up the ID (`name4`) and so when you hover it the image will change to `img/name4.jpg`. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Going to check this out real quick. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I think it is interrupting some other javascript I have on  my page. Do you think it might be becuase I have the other script to load when the document is ready aswell?

Comment: @AbrahamGuzman No, you can have multiple `$(document).ready(...)`. One possibility is the bracket that I'd missed off: the last line was accidentally `}` instead of `});`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this more simply

```
$(function() {
    $("#pet1")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = 'first image path';
            $("#mainimage").attr("src", src);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src2 ='Default image path';
            $(this).attr("src", src2;
        });
});
```

Similllar for second image and for shortening even this you can give a class to every link you want and then by using **$(element).each() function and "data" attribute of html5** you can manage it in more cool way

Comment: Thanks for your reply man! How does this work. I have <li> tags with anchors in them and want to manipulate an images with id="mainimage" The above code was just an expample. Can you explain on how to work with this script?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" id="theImage">
<p><a href="#" class="yourClass" data-img="http://placehold.it/300x150/f00">Red</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="yourClass" data-img="http://placehold.it/300x150/00f">Blue</a></p>
```

JS:

```
$('.yourClass').hover(function() {
  var newImg = $(this).data('img');
$('#theImage').attr('src',newImg)
}, function() {
  $('#theImage').attr('src','http://placehold.it/300x150')
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqmsa6k7/1/)